# vsts new repo has a gitignore option for many platforms/languages but not .net/c#

Tags: c#, .net, git, azure-devops, gitignore

I noticed that VSTS has an "Add a .gitignore" dropdown with many different platforms/languages options for selection. For example, I could select the option of "Ruby" which I'm assuming would provide a default filter for all file types in a compiled Ruby project which should generally not be checked in to a git repo. However, no option exists in the dropdown for .NET/C#.  Does VSTS include some type of equivalent gitignore file within C#/.NET files by default?  Or is there some type of default global filter build into VSTS which enforces this?

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/

Comment: It seems that the available .gitignore templates in Azure DevOps come from GitHub's [`gitignore` repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore), and the one for Microsoft projects is called "Visual Studio".

Answer (score 25):

The `.gitignore` template for C# is called "Visual Studio".

Comment: ah cool thanks.  so vs will enforce typical gitignore rules via checkin via team explorer.  but what if I happen to do a checkin via git bash for some reason via the root of the .net project?  is there any type of similar filtering file within my project which will ensure a proper check-in filter?  or will vsts provide a similar type of filtering as vs in this particular scenario?

Comment: @user10067458 `.gitignore` files have nothing to do with Visual Studio; they simply provide patterns that should be ignored **by Git**. This means that a `.gitignore` file will work regardless of how you choose to interact with the repo. Within Visual Studio, from the command line, from SourceTree, it's all the same.

Comment: right but my question was if vsts (or vs) will gen one by default for .net/c# projects.  I searched a local class library solution and I didn't find a gitignore so I was hoping to get clarification on the particular implementation rules around this

Comment: @user10067458 If you did not initialize the VSTS git repo by adding `.gitignore` file in VSTS web page, you can add it manually by yourself by `touch .gitignore`, and then copy the content (https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) in your .gitignore file. More `.gitignore` example files for different type of projects, you can refer https://github.com/github/gitignore.

Comment: @user10067458 If Daniel's answer helps you solve the problem, can you mark the answer? And it will also benefit other members who meet similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the .gitignore we got from VSTS starts with the following preamble which contains a handy link to the .gitignore tailored for Visual Studio projects.

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.
##
## Get latest from https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new repository through Visual Studio, then the .gitignore file will be created in that repository.

For local repository:

1. Open Team explorer
2. Click manage connections
3. Click New link in Local Git Repositories
4. Specify the path and click create

For an empty git repository in VSTS:

1. Open Team explorer
2. Click Manage connections> Connect to team project
3. Choose that repository > Clone
4. Connect to that repository
5. Click New… link in Solutions section of Team explorer
6. Choose a template
7. Make sure check Create new Git repository
8. Click OK

Both of these ways can create .gitignore files with necessary content automatically.

You also can create .gitignore file when creating repository or add a .gitignore file to an empty repository by accessing that repository in web browser and click Initialize button (choose a Visual Studio first)